# USN_RECORD all values ok, except TimeStamp = 0?

Tags: delphi, computer-forensics, usn

Using below record structure and function I get the FileName,Reference Numbers,Versions etc. at high speed. (trying with Delphi, Win 7)

Problem is that I don't get the file DateTime (TimeStamp.QuadPart = 0)

I have added the working code. For testing I am adding the filename (shows correct) and timestamp (shows empty) to  memo1

```
procedure Tform_main.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FillFileListFromUSNJournal('C') ;
end;


procedure Tform_main.FillFileListFromUSNJournal(pDrive:Char);
var
  ARootHandle: Cardinal;
  AMFTEnumBuff: Pointer;
begin
    ARootHandle := GetRootHandle(pDrive);
    if AllocMFTEnumBuffer(ARootHandle,AMFTEnumBuff) then
      EnumMFTEntries(ARootHandle, AMFTEnumBuff, MFTEnumCallback, @pDrive) ;
end;

function Tform_main.MFTEnumCallback(AUSN: PUSNRecord; Extra: Pointer): Boolean;
var
  AName,ProgressMsg: String;
  Drive: Char;
begin
  Drive  := PChar(Extra)^;
  Result := True;
  USNRecFromPointer(AUSN) ;
end;




{
  ** uMFT.pas
  ** zm
  ** created: 13.11.2010
  **
  *  Copyright (c) 2010, Zeljko Marjanovic <xxxxxxr@gmail.com>
  *  This code is licensed under MPL 1.1
  *  For details, see http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/MPL-1.1.html
  *
}

unit uMFT;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

const
  FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM = $00000009;
  METHOD_NEITHER = 3;
  METHOD_BUFFERED = 0;
  FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0;
  FILE_SPECIAL_ACCESS = 0;
  FILE_READ_ACCESS = 1;
  FILE_WRITE_ACCESS = 2;

  ERROR_JOURNAL_DELETE_IN_PROGRESS = 1178;
  ERROR_JOURNAL_NOT_ACTIVE  = 1179;
  ERROR_JOURNAL_ENTRY_DELETED = 1181;

  FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID = $9009c;
  FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA = (FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM shl 16) or (FILE_ANY_ACCESS shl 14) or (44 shl 2) or METHOD_NEITHER;
  FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL = (FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM shl 16) or (FILE_ANY_ACCESS shl 14) or (46 shl 2) or METHOD_NEITHER;
  FSCTL_CREATE_USN_JOURNAL = (FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM shl 16) or (FILE_ANY_ACCESS shl 14) or (57 shl 2) or METHOD_NEITHER;
  FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL = (FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM shl 16) or (FILE_ANY_ACCESS shl 14) or (61 shl 2) or METHOD_BUFFERED;
  FSCTL_DELETE_USN_JOURNAL = (FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM shl 16) or (FILE_ANY_ACCESS shl 14) or (62 shl 2) or METHOD_BUFFERED;

  USN_PAGE_SIZE = $1000;
  USN_REASON_DATA_OVERWRITE = $00000001;
  USN_REASON_DATA_EXTEND = $00000002;
  USN_REASON_DATA_TRUNCATION = $00000004;
  USN_REASON_NAMED_DATA_OVERWRITE = $00000010;
  USN_REASON_NAMED_DATA_EXTEND = $00000020;
  USN_REASON_NAMED_DATA_TRUNCATION = $00000040;
  USN_REASON_FILE_CREATE = $00000100;
  USN_REASON_FILE_DELETE = $00000200;
  USN_REASON_EA_CHANGE = $00000400;
  USN_REASON_SECURITY_CHANGE = $00000800;
  USN_REASON_RENAME_OLD_NAME = $00001000;
  USN_REASON_RENAME_NEW_NAME = $00002000;
  USN_REASON_INDEXABLE_CHANGE = $00004000;
  USN_REASON_BASIC_INFO_CHANGE = $00008000;
  USN_REASON_HARD_LINK_CHANGE = $00010000;
  USN_REASON_COMPRESSION_CHANGE = $00020000;
  USN_REASON_ENCRYPTION_CHANGE = $00040000;
  USN_REASON_OBJECT_ID_CHANGE = $00080000;
  USN_REASON_REPARSE_POINT_CHANGE = $00100000;
  USN_REASON_STREAM_CHANGE = $00200000;
  USN_REASON_CLOSE = $80000000;

  USN_DELETE_FLAG_DELETE = $00000001;
  USN_DELETE_FLAG_NOTIFY = $00000002;
  USN_DELETE_VALID_FLAGS = $00000003;

  USNREC_MAJVER_OFFSET = 4;
  USNREC_MINVER_OFFSET = 8; 
  USNREC_FR_OFFSET = 8;
  USNREC_PFR_OFFSET = 16;
  USNREC_USN_OFFSET = 24;
  USNREC_TIMESTAMP_OFFSET = 32;
  USNREC_REASON_OFFSET = 40;
  USNREC_SINFO_OFFSET = 44;
  USNREC_SECID_OFFSET = 48;
  USNREC_FA_OFFSET = 52;
  USNREC_FNL_OFFSET = 56;
  USNREC_FN_OFFSET = 58;

  IOCTL_DISK_BASE = $00000007;
  IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO = (IOCTL_DISK_BASE shl 16) or (FILE_READ_ACCESS shl 14) or ($0001 shl 2) or METHOD_BUFFERED;
  PARTITION_IFS = $07; 

type
  USN_JOURNAL_DATA = record
    UsnJournalID: UInt64;
    FirstUsn: Int64;
    NextUsn: Int64;
    LowestValidUsn: Int64;
    MaxUsn: Int64;
    MaximumSize: UInt64;
    AllocationDelta: UInt64;
  end;
  TUSNJournalData = USN_JOURNAL_DATA;
  PUSNJournalData = ^TUSNJournalData;

  MFT_ENUM_DATA = record
    StartFileReferenceNumber: UInt64;
    LowUsn: Int64;
    HighUsn: Int64;
  end;
  TMFTEnumData = MFT_ENUM_DATA;
  PMFTEnumData = ^TMFTEnumData;

  CREATE_USN_JOURNAL_DATA = record
    MaximumSize: UInt64;
    AllocationDelta: UInt64;
  end;
  TCreateUSNJournalData = CREATE_USN_JOURNAL_DATA;
  PCreateUSNJournalData = ^TCreateUSNJournalData;

  USN_RECORD = record
    RecordLength: Cardinal;
    MajorVersion: Word;
    MinorVersion: Word;
    FileReferenceNumber: UInt64;
    ParentFileReferenceNumber: UInt64;
    Usn: Int64;
    TimeStamp: LARGE_INTEGER;
    Reason: Cardinal;
    SourceInfo: Cardinal;
    SecurityId: Cardinal;
    FileAttributes: Cardinal;
    FileNameLength: Word;
    FileNameOffset: Word;
    FileName: PWideChar;//   PWChar; [ss]
  end;
  TUSNRecord = USN_RECORD;
  PUSNRecord = ^TUSNRecord;

  TMFTEnumCallback = function(AUSN: PUSNRecord; Extra: Pointer = nil): Boolean of object;
  PUInt64 = ^UInt64;
  EMFTException = class(Exception);

  TUSNRecChangeType = (uceNew, uceDeleted, uceRenamed);


function USNRecFromPointer(const P: Pointer): TUSNRecord;
function GetRootHandle(const Drive: Char): Cardinal;
function CreateUSNJournal(ARootHandle: Cardinal; MaxSize, AllocationDelta: UInt64): Boolean;
function AllocMFTEnumBuffer(ARootHandle: Cardinal; var AMFTEnumBuff: Pointer): boolean;
function EnumMFTEntries(ARootHandle: Cardinal; AMFTEnumBuff: Pointer; EnumCallBack: TMFTEnumCallback;Extra: Pointer = nil): Boolean;

implementation
uses main ;

function USNRecFromPointer(const P: Pointer): TUSNRecord;
var
  PA: PAnsiChar;
begin
  PA := PAnsiChar(P);
  Result.RecordLength := PInteger(PA)^ ;
  Result.MajorVersion := PInteger(PA + USNREC_MAJVER_OFFSET)^;
  Result.MinorVersion := PInteger(PA + USNREC_MINVER_OFFSET)^;
  Result.FileReferenceNumber := PUInt64(PA + USNREC_FR_OFFSET)^;
  Result.ParentFileReferenceNumber := PUInt64(PA + USNREC_PFR_OFFSET)^;
  Result.USN := PInt64(PA + USNREC_USN_OFFSET)^;
  Result.TimeStamp.QuadPart := PInt64(PA + USNREC_TIMESTAMP_OFFSET)^;
  Result.Reason := PCardinal(PA + USNREC_REASON_OFFSET)^;
  Result.SourceInfo := PCardinal(PA + USNREC_SINFO_OFFSET)^;
  Result.SecurityId := PCardinal(PA + USNREc_SECID_OFFSET)^;
  Result.FileAttributes := PCardinal(PA + USNREC_FA_OFFSET)^;
  Result.FileNameLength := PWord(PA + USNREC_FNL_OFFSET)^;
  Result.FileNameOffset := PWord(PA + USNREC_FN_OFFSET)^;
  Result.FileName :=   PWideChar(Integer(P) + Result.FileNameOffset);
  if form_Main.memo1.lines.Count<100 then
    form_Main.memo1.lines.add(Result.FileName+' '+InttoStr(Result.TimeStamp.QuadPart)) ;

end;


// this requires admin privileges
function GetRootHandle(const Drive: Char): Cardinal;
var
  W: WideString;
  RootHandle: Cardinal;
  Flags: Cardinal;
  Access: Cardinal;
begin
  Flags := 0;
  W := '\\.\' + Drive + ':';
  Access := GENERIC_READ;
  RootHandle := CreateFileW(PWChar(W), Access, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, Flags, 0);
  if RootHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    Result := RootHandle
  else
    raise EMFTException.Create(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;

function CreateUSNJournal(ARootHandle: Cardinal; MaxSize, AllocationDelta: UInt64): Boolean;
var
  BytesRet: Cardinal;
  CreateData: TCreateUSNJournalData;
begin
  CreateData.MaximumSize := MaxSize;
  CreateData.AllocationDelta := AllocationDelta;
  Result := DeviceIoControl(ARootHandle, FSCTL_CREATE_USN_JOURNAL, @CreateData, sizeof(TCreateUSNJournalData), nil, 0, BytesRet, nil);
end;


function AllocMFTEnumBuffer(ARootHandle: Cardinal; var AMFTEnumBuff: Pointer): boolean;
var
  USNBuf: TUSNJournalData;
  ErrCode,BytesRet: Cardinal;
  EnumBuf: PMFTEnumData;
begin
  result:=false;
  if DeviceIoControl(ARootHandle, FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL, nil, 0, @USNBuf, sizeof(TUSNJournalData), BytesRet, nil) then
  begin
    GetMem(EnumBuf, sizeof(TMFTEnumData));
    EnumBuf.StartFileReferenceNumber := 0;
    EnumBuf.LowUsn := 0;
    EnumBuf.HighUsn := USNBuf.NextUsn;
    AMFTEnumBuff := EnumBuf;
    result:=true;
    exit;
  end;

  ErrCode:=GetLastError;
  if ErrCode = ERROR_JOURNAL_NOT_ACTIVE then
  begin
    // journal does not exist, create a new1 one
    if CreateUSNJournal(ARootHandle, $10000000, $100000) then
    begin
      if DeviceIoControl(ARootHandle, FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL, nil, 0, @USNBuf, sizeof(TUSNJournalData), BytesRet, nil) then
      begin
        GetMem(EnumBuf, sizeof(TMFTEnumData));
        EnumBuf.StartFileReferenceNumber := 0;
        EnumBuf.LowUsn := 0;
        EnumBuf.HighUsn := USNBuf.NextUsn;
        AMFTEnumBuff := EnumBuf;
        result:=true;
        exit;
      end;
      ErrCode:=GetLastError;
    end
    else
    begin
      ErrCode:=GetLastError;
    end;
  end;
end;

//v main function
function EnumMFTEntries(ARootHandle: Cardinal; AMFTEnumBuff: Pointer; EnumCallBack: TMFTEnumCallback;Extra: Pointer): Boolean;
const
  BUF_SIZE = sizeof(UInt64) + $10000;
var
  P: Pointer;
  MFTEnum: Pointer;
  BytesRet: Cardinal;
  PUSN: PUSNRecord;
//  TUSN: TUSNRecord;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (ARootHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) or (AMFTEnumBuff = nil) then
    Exit;

  MFTEnum := AMFTEnumBuff;
  GetMem(P, BUF_SIZE);
  try
    ZeroMemory(P, BUF_SIZE);
    while DeviceIoControl(ARootHandle, FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA, MFTEnum, sizeof(TMFTEnumData), P, BUF_SIZE, BytesRet, nil) do
    begin
      PUSN := PUSNRecord(Integer(P) + sizeof(Int64));

      while BytesRet > 60 do
      begin
        if (not EnumCallBack(PUSN, Extra)) then
          Exit;
        if PUSN.RecordLength > 0 then
          Dec(BytesRet, PUSN.RecordLength)
        else
          break;
        PUSN := PUSNRecord(Cardinal(PUSN) + PUSN.RecordLength);
        if form_Main.memo1.lines.Count>100 then
          break ;
      end;
      CopyMemory(MFTEnum, P, sizeof(Int64));
    end;
    Result := True;

  finally
    FreeMem(P);
  end;
end;
//^ main function


end.
```

Comment: Post a full example, otherwise we can not guess what's not working

Comment: Provided code doesn't cover [mcve]. We need more info!

Comment: The author returns boolean from the callback so that you can quit anytime you want, you don't have to modify the source for that. Anyway, my guess is you have to use FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL, but documentation is full of dead links currently, hard to follow anything.

Comment: FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL in place of FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL returns Error and in place of FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA returns 0 Bytes.

Comment: You can't just switch the control code and expect it to work. In fact querying is still required, that's where you get the USN to provide for the read call. At some point you have to begin trying to understand what you're doing...

Comment: @Akyuz Please guide, where am I going wrong, Am I using the wrong USN_RECORD structure ? I got the callback advice you gave me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time stamps come up 0 because `FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL` does not populate that information. This is not explicitly stated in the control code's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/9491b054-934a-4b76-bf77-f397b6386f82?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and I cannot find any official documentation where it is. But there are places that mention a `USN_RECORD` is only partially populated. Like in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232128.aspx#Appendix_A_41) which is given from `USN_RECORD_V2`'s [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn366739.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), although I'm not even sure what FSCTL the former link is talking about.

Anyway, this is inline with all the examples I can find including Microsoft's [own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/walking-a-buffer-of-change-journal-records). Below is a Delphi translation of this code. The USN information retrieved by using a `FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL` control code is used in a `DeviceIoControl` call using `FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL` to retrieve detailed information.

There are few exceptions of a direct translation, one is the retrieval of the file name, which I didn't understand how the C++ code is doing. Another is printing time stamps as this is your requirement. Also, you need to add error checking and protection blocks for resources like the volume handle or memory, etc..

The code uses the declarations from the helper unit you have included in the question. I checked the time stamps against a 3rd party freeware utility which I found [here](http://www.orionforensics.com/w_en_page/NTFS-Journal-Viewer.php) and they are in accordance.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  windows,
  uMFT;

type
  USN = LONGLONG;
const
  BUF_LEN = 4096;
var
  hVol: THandle;
  JournalData: TUSNJournalData;
  dwBytes: DWORD;
  dwRetBytes: DWORD;
  ReadData: TReadUSNJournalData;
  i: Integer;
  Buffer: array [0..BUF_LEN - 1] of Byte;
  UsnRecord: PUSNRecord;
  FileName: PWideChar;
  SysTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  hVol := CreateFile( '\\.\c:', GENERIC_READ,
      FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

  if hVol = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin
    Writeln(Format('CreateFile failed (%d)', [GetLastError]));
    Exit;
  end;

  if not DeviceIoControl(hVol, FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL, nil, 0, @JournalData,
      SizeOf(JournalData), dwBytes, nil) then begin
    Writeln(Format('Query journal failed (%d)', [GetLastError]));
    Exit;
  end;

  ZeroMemory(@ReadData, SizeOf(ReadData));
  ReadData.ReasonMask := $FFFFFFFF;
  ReadData.UsnJournalID := JournalData.UsnJournalID;

  Writeln(Format('Journal ID: %x', [JournalData.UsnJournalID]));
  Writeln(Format('FirstUsn: %x' + sLineBreak, [JournalData.FirstUsn]));

  for i := 0 to 10 do begin
    FillChar(Buffer, BUF_LEN, 0);

    if not DeviceIoControl(hVol, FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL, @ReadData,
        SizeOf(ReadData), @Buffer, BUF_LEN, dwBytes, nil) then begin
      Writeln(Format('Read journal failed (%d)', [GetLastError]));
      Exit;
    end;
    dwRetBytes := dwBytes - SizeOf(USN);

    // Find the first record
    UsnRecord := PUsnRecord(NativeInt(@Buffer) + SizeOf(USN));

    Writeln('****************************************');

    while dwRetBytes > 0 do begin

      Writeln(Format('USN: %x', [UsnRecord.Usn]));

      GetMem(FileName, UsnRecord.FileNameLength + SizeOf(Char));
      Move(Pointer(NativeInt(UsnRecord) + UsnRecord.FileNameOffset)^, FileName^,
          UsnRecord.FileNameLength);
      FileName[UsnRecord.FileNameLength div 2] := #0;
      Writeln(Format('File name: %s', [FileName]));
      FreeMem(FileName);

      FileTimeToSystemTime(@UsnRecord.TimeStamp, SysTime);
      Writeln(Format('Time stamp: %s', [DateTimeToStr(SystemTimeToDateTime(SysTime))]));
      Writeln(Format('Reason: %x', [UsnRecord.Reason]));
      Writeln;

      dwRetBytes := dwRetBytes - UsnRecord.RecordLength;

      // Find the next record
      UsnRecord := PUsnRecord(NativeInt(UsnRecord) + UsnRecord.RecordLength);
    end;
  end;
  CloseHandle(hVol);

  Writeln;
  Writeln('End of sample');
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort , will need to study deeper and will getback.

Answer (score -1):

The system returns 0, read "Remarks" for FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA on the page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364584(v=vs.85).aspx
CreateFile example:

```
H: THandle;
```

[...]

```
H := CreateFile(PWChar('\\.\' + DiskName + ':\' + FileName),
    GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
```

[...]

```
if (H = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then //GetLastError()
  Memo.Lines.Add(FileName + ' 0')
else
begin
  GetfileTime(H, @FTime, nil, nil);
  Memo.Lines.Add(FileName + ' ' + DateTimeToStr(FileTimeToDateTime(FTime)));
end;
```

[...]

```
CloseHandle(H);
```

Comment: The TimeStamp always comes as 0, I have added Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to the best of my abilities

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Why do you link from FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA documentation when there's nothing in the code that use it? Why do you give an example for CreateFile when the code in the question does not have any problem with it?

Comment: FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA and FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA relate to the same structure. In my opinion, the area being read, regardless of what to use, does not store information about the date and time. In FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA description missing information that is in FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA. CreateFile gives us a handle, thanks to which we can use GetFileTime to read the date and time.

Comment: What does the timestamp of a journal entry have got anything to do with file date time? You have to read a little bit about the NTFS journal.